# JQuery Toggle Multiple Divs + Read More/Read Less

Tags: jquery, css, image

Brand new to jQuery as I'm sure you'll soon be able to tell.

I've been browsing the forums looking for solutions to two main issues I've been experiencing:

- Independent toggle between multiple divs &
- Toggle between *'Read More'* & *'Show Less'*

Below is the script I'm using for the page, however when I select a specific div, which reveals additional content underneath, the display image is hidden & replaced with *'Show Less'*.

```
$(".stage-description").slideUp();

$(".stage-logo").click(function(){
    $(".stage-description").not($(this).next()).hide(1);
    $(this).next(".stage-description").slideToggle("1");
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Show Less' ? "Read More" : "Show Less");
});
```

Below is an example page where I'm experiencing this issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/raym01/qmg4bxra/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You mean you want this? :
when the user clicks on each img, the text of that slides down and after clicking on another img, current text slide up and the text related to clicked img slide down?

Comment: Nah, i'd like the image to remain visible after its been clicked, with only the "read more" within the 'a href' changing to read less etc. I think the issue, is something to do with the last line of code as when i remove this line, the toggle works as expected, minus the 'Read More' change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 5th line to :

```
$(this).children().last().text( 
    $(this).children().last().text() == 'Show Less' ? "Read More" : "Show Less"
);
```

For accessing multiple elements you can use .each() and use $(this)

Example:

```
$('.article-less-button').each(function (){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggle();
        or
        $(this).parent().children().last().toggle();//to toggle another element 
        ...
    })
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Cheers, there appears to be an issue with this. Im not sure if it's this code or from anything prior to this, but when i select/toggle an image and the 'read more' text changes to 'show less', however if i don't deselect that image the 'Show Less' text will still display even though ive selected another image for example. This then causes the Read more/less sequence to display incorrectly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you could process all the elements with each function to prevent this..

like this :

`$('.article-less-button').each(function (){`

Comment: Sorry being a complete newbie what would the end script look like? Im not really sure where to add that finial command?? Sorry to hassle

Comment: add `$(".read-more").not($(this).children().last()).text("Read More");` before slideToggle line.. it's kinda hacky but will do the trick

Comment: Perfect, I'll take hacky for the time being!! Thanks for all of your help :)